# MySQL check if rows exists and delete it in the same query

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to do the following in one query, I was wandering if it is even possible:

```
$rowsQ = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (a='a' AND b='b')");
if($rowsQ->num_rows){
    $mysql->query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE (a='a' AND b='b')");
}
```

I have seen a similar thing with WHERE EXISTS but only with a query for a different table like so:

```
$mysql->query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE table.id = table2.id)");
```

Is it possible to do on the same table though and if so do I have to rewrite the same conditions or is there a shorter way?

Comment: Why dont you run the delete anyway?It wont delete anything if the conditions are not met

Comment: What if rows do not exist? Do you really need to check if they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `DELETE`, in case row doesn't exists with the specified values, the query would return with out doing any thing. you can avoid the `select`

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE a ='a' and b='b'
```

Comment: Aaa, stupid me for some reason I was sure it will return false, thank you!